# Could not build url for endpoint 'http://www.youtube.com/results/search_query/kerem'. Did you mean 'static' instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'hello'


@app.route('/<variable>')
def daily(variable):
    youtubeUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/results/search_query/"+variable 
    return redirect(url_for(youtubeUrl))
```

this redirection not working. İ want to be search 'variable' on youtube but always 500 intervel server and this error text = Could not build url for endpoint 'http://www.youtube.com/results/search_query/kerem'. Did you mean 'static' instead?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9zS8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url_for` is made for generating URLs using provided method, for example in your code `url_for('hello')` will return `/`.

Change your `return redirect(url_for(youtubeUrl))` line to `return redirect(youtubeUrl)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because you are using http instead of https in the url
also consider using f strings like this for example

```
youtubeUrl = f"https://www.youtube.com/results/search_query/{variable}"
```

Comment: Firstly, thank u but unfortunately no change